# Issue accessing TextService in remote function

Tags: lua, roblox

So basically I'm making a script so you can set your name and gender with a gui

I made the script and 4 scripts related to it

1. Displays the gui if your datastore doesn't have a firstName already set
2. remotefunction to save the players name and gender from script 4
3. remotefunction using textservice to check if the players name is filtered (since script 4 is localscript so it cant access datastoreservice or textservice)
4. script related to gui that uses script 2 and 3 alongside the gui to save teh stuff

issue comes in with the third script because the text doesnt pass through and it seems like the remote event doesnt even happen, any way to fix this

1.

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local playerDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("ChaosDataStore03")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local NamingGui = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("NamingGui")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local success, result = pcall(function()
        return playerDataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end)

    if not success or result.firstName == nil then
        local guiClone = NamingGui:Clone()
        guiClone.Parent = player.PlayerGui
    end
end)
```

2. 

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local playerDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("ChaosDataStore03")

game.ReplicatedStorage.SaveNameAndGender.OnServerInvoke = function(player, name, gender)
    print("Saving...")
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        playerDataStore:SetAsync("firstName_"..player.UserId, name)
        playerDataStore:SetAsync("playerGender_"..player.UserId, gender)
    end)
    if success then
        print("Saved successfully")
    else
        print("Save Failed: "..err)
    end
end
```

3. 

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.FilterCheck.OnServerInvoke = function(player, text)
    local TextService = game:GetService("TextService")
    print("Checking Name.")
    local filtered = TextService:FilterStringAsync(text, player.UserId)

    if filtered == text then
        print("Safe")
    else
        print("Filtered")
    end
end
```

4. 

```
local NamingGui = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.NamingGui
local NameBox = NamingGui.NameBox
local MaleButton = NamingGui.MaleButton
local FemaleButton = NamingGui.FemaleButton
local ConfirmButton = NamingGui.ConfirmButton

local genderstuff = ""

MaleButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    genderstuff = "Male"
    print("Male Selected.")
end)

FemaleButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    genderstuff = "Female"
    print("Female Selected.")
end)

ConfirmButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    print("Checking...")
    local name = NameBox.Text
    if #name <= 15 and genderstuff ~= "" then
        local success, result = game.ReplicatedStorage.FilterCheck:InvokeServer(name)

        if success and result == "Safe" then
            game.ReplicatedStorage.SaveNameAndGender:InvokeServer(name, genderstuff)
            NamingGui:Destroy()
        end
    end
end)
```

What is expected is when there is a name in NameBox, and a gender has been selected, once confirmbutton is clicked, the game checks if the name is filtered or not, and if it isn't, it saves the name and gender to the datastore, outputting "Safe" (When the text is not filtered) and "Saved" (Once the text is saved). Instead, however, it usually only gets up to "Checking Name" in script 3 before nothing else is outputted afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Safe")
return unpack{true,"Safe"}
else
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?